# RecyclerView images show artifacts

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView which has a CircularImageView and I'm loading the images from a url into the imageView using Picasso. I have added a fade animation too.
But when I scroll quickly, the recyclerView shows artifacts of the previous images.

[image: artifacts]

This is my Adapter:

```
public class CastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CastAdapter.CastHolder> {
private List<String> cast;
private Context mContext;

public CastAdapter(List<String> cast, Context mContext) {
    this.cast = cast;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CastHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_movie_cast, viewGroup, false);
    return new CastHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CastHolder castHolder, int i) {
    String url = TMDB_IMAGE + "w185" + cast.get(i);
    Picasso.get().load(url).into(castHolder.target);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cast.size();
}

class CastHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private CircleImageView imageView;
    private Animation fadeIn;
    Target target;

    CastHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cast);
        fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeIn.setDuration(200);
        fadeIn.reset();

        target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried to disable the animation, and the artifacts were still there

Comment: try cancelling the animation in `onViewRecycled`

Comment: Didn't work out.

Comment: can you post code of what you tried?

Comment: @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull CastHolder holder) {
        holder.imageView.setAnimation(null);
    }

Comment: do you get this with simple ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You must have set some animation duration to the fading animation. Since you're scrolling before that animation ends, you are able to see them even after they are scrolled away.

Try reducing the animation.

Comment: It made no difference. And the animation speed is already 200 ms.

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/mythio/9aa39036128fbd1075caf4e1d625b8c3)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why it happened meanwhile, you can try using a custom animation drawable. Maybe it will work for you.






`code` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
          android:duration="2000"/>
     </set>

Comment: Artifacts still there.

Comment: Oh, I'll let you know soon.

Comment: Sure! btw. the artifacts are still shows even when the animation is disabled completely

Comment: Oh, okay. At least we know it's not because of Animation.

Comment: I think its because of the target of Picasso which is messing up with the images. I removed the target and now it works. I have applied animation in the viewHolder and that does the job! Thanks! [link](https://gist.github.com/mythio/70772cb591a51f8ef11ee72a62e00862)

Comment: Oh perfect, great! 